# Как получить время отправленного сообщения в Telegram боте на Python

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

Мне нужно получить время отправленного пользователем сообщения, чтобы внести их в БД mySQL. Я использую aiogram

Comment: дату и время вы можете получить из `message.date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Дата пересланного сообщения***

Можно использовать метод `message.forward_date`, данная инструкция возвращает исходную дату отправленного пересланного сообщения. Чтобы продемонстрировать, я написал тестового бота, который формирует дату и время в виде сообщения, а так же принтует результат от `forward_date`.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

bot = Bot(token="<ТВОЙ КЛЮЧ СЮДА>")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def handle_message(message: types.Message):
    forward_date = message.forward_date
    formatted_date = forward_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    formatted_time = forward_date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    response_text = f"Дата и время сообщения: {formatted_date} {formatted_time}"
    print(forward_date)
    await message.reply(response_text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Если переслать сообщение данному боту, он вернет в виде сообщения:

[image: результат работы бота]

Вывод в консоли:

```
2023-05-24 17:18:00
```

---

***Дата отправленного сообщения***

Чтобы получить дату сообщения отправленного в бота, можно использовать метод `message.date`, по аналогии в коде выше нужно изменить метод с `message.forward_date` на `message.date`

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод в консоли:

```
2023-05-25 08:59:47
```